# monotouch equivalent of LoadDatalWithBaseURL & emptying the cache

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm having two issues with porting some Android code across to the iPhone. Firstly is that I need something along the lines of LoadDataWithBaseURL. Problem is this. In the code, I generate a webpage. The page does some funky things with Javascript and the world is good. Works fine on the droid, I generate, send to the activity for the webview and then use LoadDataWithBaseURL.

Unfortunately, on the iPhone, it works first time. If I add something to the page and resend, I get the first thing on a list to show and nothing else. This is with LoadHtmlString.

```
string contentDirectoryPath = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, "Content/");
        this.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (delegate {
            this.webView.LoadHtmlString (myGeneratedPage, new NSUrl (contentDirectoryPath, true));
        });
```

There is a monotouch method called LoadData which seems similar, but I'm not clear if NSData data is the same as the string data on the android app.

A simpler solution may be to clear the cache... But again, I'm not sure how to and it's confusing if I need to do the app cache *or* safari's cache.

I've looked around and there is a solution, but it's in objective C and not monotouch. Unlike Java to C#, I've not touched obj-c, so don't know where to start.

Any help on these would be greatly appreciated

PFJ

Answer (score 3):

I have been working with caches in an iPhone Monotouch project I have been working on.

Regards to your simpler solution, to clear the application cache I do this:

```
NSUrlCache cache = NSUrlCache.SharedCache;
cache.RemoveAllCachedResponses();
```

I know the name SharedCache seems to indicate that it would be a cross-application cache, but I found clearing Safari's cache had no effect on my application's caching. Plus apps on the iPhone are heavily sandboxed so I wouldn't think that you could clear Safari's cache.

My experience with the iPhone simulator has shown that the line `NSUrlCace.SharedCache` creates a cache for the application. This can be seen by navigating to this folder on your Mac:

```
Library/ApplicationSupport/iPhone Simulator/6.0/<your app id>/Library/Caches/
```

There should be a folder with your package name and a file within it named "Cache.db". I think the existence of this file in this location furthermore supports the fact that it is the application's cache, so you should be safe clearing it etc.

Since there isn't too much documentation on the MonoTouch website about NSUrlCache and how they implement their methods, this is the best I can work out.

Hopefully you can find some way to use cache clearing to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to LoadData is an NSData that contains your HTML content.

Comment: The code now looks like this :

    string contentDirectoryPath = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, "Content/");
    NSData myPage = NSData.FromString (myGeneratedPage);
    webView.AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
    webView.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (delegate {
 webView.LoadData (myPage, "text/html", "UTF-8", new NSUrl (contentDirectoryPath, true));

which looks like it should now be correct. This though is still not giving the expected results (page with new content generated). On droid I can have the contentURL as null. How can this be done on the iPhone?